# Change background color of RecyclerView corresponding to specific item in list when it is not loaded

Tags: java, android, user-interface, colors, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView in my activity that displays a bunch of items in a list. I have a small control panel that changes the background color of the items in that list. I want scroll the absolute first item in the list (not the first *visible* item in the list) and change its background color as well. When I use `scrollToPosition(0)` though, it doesn't scroll and when I attempt to change the color of the first item in the list, it's not loaded and so I get null. Here's my code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int currentRound = currentEncounter.getCurrentRound();
        int oldIndex = currentEncounter.getCurrentTurnIndex();

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.encounter_activity_next_turn_button:
            int idx = currentEncounter.getCurrentTurnIndex();
            participantsLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(idx, 160);
            participantsLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(currentEncounter.getCurrentTurnIndex()).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            currentEncounter.nextTurn();

            if(currentRound != currentEncounter.getCurrentRound()) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.encounter_activity_current_round_text_view)).setText(Integer.toString(currentEncounter.getCurrentRound()));
                  participantsLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(1, 160);
                    participantsLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
                    Log.d(LOG_RECYCLE_VIEW, "Should have scrolled to top");
                } else
                    participantsLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(currentEncounter.getCurrentTurnIndex(), 160);
               participantsLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(currentEncounter.getCurrentTurnIndex()).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
               participantAdapter.setCurrentCreatureIndex(currentEncounter.getCurrentTurnIndex());

            break;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: sorry I couldn't understand your requirement. Do you want just the very first item to have a different back ground? If yes is the back ground color fixed?

Comment: I wanted a way to change the background of any given view in a RecyclerView and have that background color be fixed for the specific item in the model it represents. I ended up figuring it out by creating my own layout manager.